# Sleep / Hibernate Windows if no user input happens at X time

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, hibernate, energy

Basically I need to sleep / hibernate a Windows 10 PC if it doesn't register any user input (mouse click, keyboard stroke) at 15 minutes, independently if there is a process preventing it (full screen video, game, etc).

Comment: Will the built in power management features not fulfill these requirements? They operate based on inactivity on the system and you can set it to pretty much any amount of time.

Comment: AFAIK No. Windows only prevents sleep if a process is in full-screen mode (video, game) or if its sharing media over the network, even if the user clicks something or not. I need to remove these restrictions.